Proof of $1/(1+|x|^k) \in L^p(\mathbb(R)^d) $ for $k>d/p$
In my analysis script the professor states that
$$\text{for } k>\frac{d}{p},\ \frac{1}{1+|x|^k} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d).$$
I tried to proove the statement but I'm unable to. Here is how far I came:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{1+|x|^k} ^p \ dx = 
\int \frac{1}{1+r^k} ^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ \sin^{d-2}(\phi_1)\dots\sin(\phi_{d-1})dr\ d\phi_1\dots d\phi_{d-1} = 
C \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+r^k} ^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr$$
Substituting $1+r^k = x$ we get:
$$r = (x-1)^\frac{1}{k},\ 
\frac{dx}{dr} = k\cdot r^{k-1} = k\cdot (x-1)^\frac{k-1}{k},\ 
dr = \frac{1}{k}\cdot (x-1)^\frac{k}{k-1} dx.$$
The integral becomes:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+r^k} ^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr = 
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} \cdot (x-1)^\frac{d-1}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k}\cdot (x-1)^\frac{k}{k-1} dx = 
\frac{1}{k}\cdot \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} \cdot (x-1)^\frac{d-1}{k-1} dx.$$
The integral surely converges if
$$\frac{d-1}{k-1}<p-1 
\Leftrightarrow \frac{d-1}{p-1}<k-1
\Leftrightarrow \frac{d-1}{p-1}+1<k.$$
Which is not correct!?
Does anyone has a better solution to this problem?

$\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{1+r^k}) ^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr=\int_{0}^{1} (\frac{1}{1+r^k}) ^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr+\int_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{1+r^k} )^p \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr$. The first term is clearly finite. The second term does not exceed $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^{kp}} \cdot r^{d-1}\ dr=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {r^{kp+1-d}}dr$ which is finite since $kp+1-d>1$.

Thank you for the clear and fast answer :) Have a great day!

Welcome! If you directly handle integral from $0$ to $\infty$, you will run into problem at $0$ or at $\infty$. So integrals of this type have to be handled by splitting them into two parts, separating $0$ and $\infty$.
